# How to set "Default:LinkToExistingAccess" option for a Sharepoint Online site using PnP Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is it possible to do the below task using PnP powershell? What is the equivalent command?

Set-SPOSite -Identity $site -DefaultLinkToExistingAccess $true -DefaultLinkPermission "view"

Answer (score 0):

To change the setting for the default link type, you can do it like this:

```
$site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url "https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$site.DefaultLinkToExistingAccess = $true
$site.Update()
$site.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

You can also use something as in the code below, to change other sharing settings for the site:

```
Set-PnPSite -Sharing ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly -DefaultLinkPermission View
```

Comment: I have already tried this but this is setting to  "Existing Guests Only"  option under "External Sharing"  . I am looking for "People with Existing access"  under "Default sharing Link Type"

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: This does not work ether. I am getting below message The property 'DefaultLinkToExistingAccess' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: Can you show the full command you're using?